# Download website over sftp/ftp in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, sftp

In Jenkins I I would like to have a job that does a one-way sync of a sftp folder with a local folder. The online sftp server content should be downloaded to my local development machine. What is the best way to do this in Jenkins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get something working using a Python script. Basically pysftp is the package you want to use. Posting here if anyone else needs to do something similar: http://sebastiannilsson.com/en/blogg/python-for-sftp-and-mysql-backup/